# login authentication and download multiple files using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, wget

Im trying to download several files from a website. The link for each file is different and are stored in a txt file. To download the file user has to login. However, there are over 10000 files which I am trying to download.

Is there any better way to provide login credentials so that, authentication is done only once and files are iteratively downloaded as given in the code below.

```
import wget
# import requests
f = open("datalinks.txt", "r")
lnks = f.readlines()

for eachlink in lnks:
    if '.h5' in eachlink:
        file_url = eachlink
        wget.download(file_url)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the site and how the login process works it is going to be difficult to help you.

Some general advise would be to use the `requests.Session()` functionality, this allows you to keep a session open for the duration of your scraping and the cookies are maintained throughout. Here is an example:

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()

login_url = 'https://www.website.com/login'
username = 'joe'
password = 'hunter2'

payload = {'username': username,
            'password': password}

header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36'}

entry = s.post(login_url,headers=header,data=payload)
print(entry.status_code)

### continue scraping with s Session
data = s.get('other_url')
print(data.content)
```

Updating now that you've provided the url, it's more complicated than I anticipated! You'll need to get a login token first which is loaded by javascript, I've chosen to use Selenium:

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = 'https://gportal.jaxa.jp/gpr/auth'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"path_to_your_chrome_driver") #https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)

cookies = driver.get_cookies()

driver.close()
driver.quit()

cookie_str = ''
for cookie in cookies:
    name = cookie['name']
    if 'csrf_token' in name:
        fuel_csrf_token = cookie['value']
    value = cookie['value']
    cookie_str += f'{name}={value}; '

print(cookie_str)
print(fuel_csrf_token)

s = requests.Session()

username = 'name'
pw = 'password'

payload = {
    'account':username,
    'password':pw,
    'fuel_csrf_token': fuel_csrf_token
    }

headers = {
    'Accept':'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'Cookie': cookie_str,
    'Host':'gportal.jaxa.jp',
    'Origin':'https://gportal.jaxa.jp',
    'Referer':'https://gportal.jaxa.jp/gpr/auth',
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36',
    'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'
    }

login_url = 'https://gportal.jaxa.jp/gpr/auth/authenticate.json'

login = s.post(login_url,headers=headers,data=payload)
print(login)
```

Comment: I have used login credentials and tried this code. Entry status I am getting as 200.  I am not getting any error while executing the code, however, i am not able to save the data. The data I am trying to download is in .h5 format. The webportal I am trying to login is https://gportal.jaxa.jp/gpr/auth